# How to convert relational algebra division into a sql division query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table:

```
Flights(Flno, Origin, Destination, Distance, departs, Arrives) <br>
Flight Instance(Flno, Day, Aid)<br>
Aircraft(Aid, Make, Model, CrusingRange)<br>
Certied(Eid, Make, Model)<br>
Employee(Eid, Ename, Salary)<br>
Fight Attendant(Flno, Day, Eid, Role)<br> <br>
```

I know how to write it in relational algebra it would be:

∏Eid, Destination (σeid, destination (Flight_Attendant flno=flno * Flights)) / ∏Destination (σDestination(Flights))

How do I convert this in sql? so the result would be list of employees who have been to all the cities.

Comment: [Relational Division in SQL The Easy Way](http://gregorulm.com/relational-division-in-sql-the-easy-way/) - double negation

Comment: Show us your attempt and we can help. We're thrilled to have you here and we don't do homework from scratch.

Comment: select eid, Destination from flight_attendant cross join flights where flight_attendant.flno=flights.flno 

This is what I have and it gives me list of all the eids and all the destinations but I want list of eid that went to all the destinations not just some. I'm not sure whats the next step or if I'm heading in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SET @TotalDestinations = (SELECT COUNT(AUX.Destination) FROM
                   (select distinct Destination from Flights) AS AUX);

SELECT A.eid, Employee.Ename -- select only those who traveled to all destinations
FROM
(
    -- know all the destinations for all assistant
    SELECT DISTINCT Flight_attendant.eid, Flights.Destination
    FROM Flight_attendant 
    INNER JOIN Flights ON Flight_attendant.flno=Flights.flno
) AS A
INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.Eid = A.Eid
GROUP BY A.eid, Employee.Ename
HAVING COUNT(*) = @TotalDestinations
```